# Verificar tempo ocioso do aplicativo

Tags: java, android

Qual a maneira mais eficiente de verificar a ociosidade do aplicativo? Eu preciso encerrar o app caso não tenha interação com ele a um determinado tempo.
Tenho uma solução funcional, porém talvez exista algo mais apropriado que não encontrei.
Segue solução atual:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // compara data (Date) do útimo toque da tela com a data atual
    if(SavedUtil.isIdleExceeded(this)) {
        // Vai para tela de login
        handleLogout(null);
    }

    // salva data do último toque na tela
    SavedUtil.setLastAppTouch(this);

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Estou recuperando e salvando em `SharedPreferences` a data do último toque na tela. Acho um pouco custoso, por isso a pergunta.